# Calculate the distance between 2 locations and calculate a price

Tags: google-maps-api-3

So basically I have this script (credits to 1stwebdesigner.com and geocodezip) which calculates the distance between 4 locations.
Location 1, location 2, location 3, location 4.
I now need to calculate the distance between location2 and location 3.
and also get that distance and display it and display a price according to this formula

1. 0-10kms = $99,
2. 11-20kms plus $5 per each additional km,
3. 21 - 35kms plus $3.75 per each additional km,
4. 36kms+ plus $3.50 per each additional km,

How do I go about this?

So far I have this (Credits to Rajaprabhu)
([Price Calculation based on the distance covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179939/price-calculation-based-on-the-distance-covered))
, problem 1 is, the formula is wrong for my situation and problem 2 is the formula isn't getting the distance from the previous calculation.

```
var request = {
    origin:location2, 
    destination:location3,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
{
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
    {
        var distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
        var duration = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
        var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
        dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
        dvDistance.innerHTML += "The one way Distance is: " + distance + "<br />";
        dvDistance.innerHTML += "The one way Duration is: " + duration;

        //calculate the one way price using the klms
        var kms = distance;
        var price_1 = (kms > 0) ? 3 : 0; kms =  (kms > 0)? kms - 1 :  0;
        var price_2 = (kms - 14) > 0 ? (14 * 1.60) : (kms * 1.60); kms = (kms-14)>0 ? kms - 14 : 0;
        var price_3 = (kms - 15) > 0 ? (15 * 1.40) : (kms * 1.40); kms = (kms-15)>0 ? kms - 15 : 0;
        var price_4 = (kms > 0) ? (kms * 1.20) : 0;

        document.getElementById("displayprice").innerHTML = "the one way price is: " + (price_1 + price_2 + price_3 + price_4);


    }
});
```

Stuck on the formula now. 
1. anything over 35km gives a incorrect result.
2. 10km and under should really default to $99.

```
//calculate the one way price using the klms
                var kms = distance;
                console.log(kms);
                var price_1 = (kms > 0) ? 99 : 0; kms =  (kms > 0)? kms - 10 :  0;
                var price_2 = (kms - 10) > 0 ? (10 * 5.00) : (kms * 5.00); kms = (kms-10)>0 ? kms - 10 : 0;
                var price_3 = (kms - 20) > 0 ? (15 * 3.75) : (kms * 3.75); kms = (kms-20)>0 ? kms - 20 : 0;
                var price_4 = (kms > 0) ? (kms * 3.50) : 0;
```

Comment: I added the code from the original 2 way calculation just below directionsDisplay.setMap and it works, but it puts the output in the totally wrong spot. I want it to output just below the 'Sunday Price'
And when I try to alter the output with say *2 multiplier I just get NaN result. so I'm totally lost when it comes to adding the formula.

Comment: Update: So I've added the code for the location2 - location 3, distance and duration calculation. and I now have it displaying in the correct spot.
How do I apply the formula to the klms? 
ie: 0-10kms = $99, 11-20kms $5 per each km, 21 - 35kms $3.75 per each km, 36kms + $3.50 per each km,

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Distance):

> **google.maps.Distance object specification**
>
> A representation of distance as a numeric value and a display string.
>
> Properties
>
> - **text** | Type:  string | A string representation of the distance value, using the UnitSystem specified in the request.
> - **value** | Type:  number | The distance in meters.

Your distance is a string: `var distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;`

You should use the numeric value (in meters):

```
var distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value/1000;
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dL43udz0/15/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
// New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.00594130000002)
// Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)
// Philadelphia, PA, USA (39.9525839, -75.16522150000003)
// Baltimore, MD, USA (39.2903848, -76.61218930000001)


var location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.005941);
var location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.735657, -74.1723667);
var location3 = new google.maps.LatLng(39.9525839, -75.1652215);
var location4 = new google.maps.LatLng(39.2903848, -76.6121893);

function initialize() {
  // create a new map object
  // set the div id where it will be shown
  // set the map options
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 42,
      lng: -72
    },
    zoom: 4
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  // show route between the points
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


  var request = {
    origin: location1,
    waypoints: [{
      location: location2,
    }, {
      location: location3,
    }],
    destination: location4,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].duration.text + "<br />";
      }
      computeTotalDistance(response);
      var request = {
        origin: location2,
        destination: location3,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          var distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
          var duration = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
          var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
          dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
          dvDistance.innerHTML += "The one way Distance (segment 2) is: " + distance + "<br />";
          dvDistance.innerHTML += "The one way Duration (segment 2) is: " + duration;

          //calculate the one way price using the klms
          var kms = distance;
          console.log(kms);
          var price_1 = (kms > 0) ? 3 : 0;
          kms = (kms > 0) ? kms - 1 : 0;
          var price_2 = (kms - 14) > 0 ? (14 * 1.60) : (kms * 1.60);
          kms = (kms - 14) > 0 ? kms - 14 : 0;
          var price_3 = (kms - 15) > 0 ? (15 * 1.40) : (kms * 1.40);
          kms = (kms - 15) > 0 ? kms - 15 : 0;
          var price_4 = (kms > 0) ? (kms * 1.20) : 0;

          document.getElementById("displayprice").innerHTML = "the one way price (segment 2) is: $" + (price_1 + price_2 + price_3 + price_4).toFixed(2);
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("directions response " + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var totalDist = 0;
  var totalTime = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
  }
  totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "total distance is: " + totalDist + " km<br>total time is: " + (totalTime / 60).toFixed(2) + " minutes<br>total price is: $" + ((totalTime / 60).toFixed(2) * 2.1) + " dollars<br>saturday price is: $" + ((totalTime / 60).toFixed(2) * 2.35) + " dollars<br>sunday price is: $" + ((totalTime / 60).toFixed(2) * 2.6) + " dollars";
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="dvDistance"></div>
<div id="displayprice"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
<div id="directions_panel"></div>
```