# Integrating googles distance Matrix api

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this piece of code but it needs to have googles distance matrix api integrated into it. I'm confused as to how this can be done as I didn't do it when I first wrote out the code.
I should get your current location and the manual lat and long of "the cake shop", display the road route and then also display the estimated travel time when the cake shop marker is clicked.
Thanks

```js
< script >
  function detectBrowser() {
    var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
    var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map");
    if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1) {
      mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
      mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
    } else {
      mapdiv.style.width = '40%';
      mapdiv.style.height = '40%';
    }
  }
var myLatLng;
var latit;
var longit;

function geoSuccess(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

  myLatLng = {
    lat: latitude,
    lng: longitude
  };
  var mapProp = {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  //call renderer to display directions
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'My location'
  });
  var markers = [
    ['Cakeshop', -35.2442802, 149.08840750000002],
    ['my current location', latitude, longitude]
  ];
  // Info Window Content
  var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
      '<h3>Cakeshop</h3>' +
      '<p>Home to custom made cakes!</p>' +
      '<img src="Logo.png" width="150px" height="150px">' +
      '<p>Latitude: -35.2442802<br>Longitude: 149.08840750000002</p>' +
      '</div>'
    ],
  ];
  // Display multiple markers on a map
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker, i;
  // Loop through the array of markers & place each one on the map
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][0]
    });
    // Allow each marker to have an info window
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        latit = marker.getPosition().lat();
        longit = marker.getPosition().lng();
        console.log("lat: " + latit);
        console.log("lng: " + longit);
      }
    })(marker, i));
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      directionsService.route({
        // origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
        origin: myLatLng,
        // destination: marker.getPosition(),
        destination: {
          lat: latit,
          lng: longit
        },
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    });
    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}
// function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
//     directionsService.route({
//         // origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
//         origin: myLatLng,
//         destination: marker.getPosition(),
//         travelMode: 'DRIVING'
//     }, function(response, status) {
//         if (status === 'OK') {
//             console.log('all good');
//             directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
//         } else {
//             window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
//         }
//     });
// }
function geoError() {
  alert("Google Maps will be unable to give you accurate directions");
}

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
    // alert("Geolocation is supported by this browser.");
  } else {
    alert("Browser's Stuffed");
  }
} <
/script>
```

```css
.googlemap {
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="googlemap" id="googleMap"></div>
```

Comment: The posted code uses the `DistanceService`, not the `DistanceMatrix`. What are you trying to do with the `DistanceMatrix`?  If you only have one origin/destination pair, the `DistanceService` should work fine (it returns the distance and duration of the route).

Comment: Do you mean DirectionsService? Isn't the Distance Matrix service needed to give the estimated distance of the trip as directed by the route that the directions service returns?

Comment: No.  The directions service returns the distance and duration of the route that it returns (you might need to add up the values for the legs).  Related question: [Calculate the distance between 2 locations and calculate a price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658640/calculate-the-distance-between-2-locations-and-calculate-a-price)